# Как правильно написать T-SQL запрос для отбора данных по реквизиту с типом "число"?

Tags: sql-server, 1с

Есть T-SQL запрос, который работает в среде 1С (1С 7.7) с MS SQL. Проблема состоит в том, что SQL неправильно отрабатывает условие сравнения реквизита типа `Число` из 1С со списком целых чисел, который передается в запрос командой `УложитьСписокОбъектов` или `УложитьСписокОбъектов13`. Выдается ошибка:

> "State 42000, native 8114, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Запрос отрабатывает нормально, если закомментировать все, что касается реквизита `Доппараметр`. Непонятно, почему выдается ошибка о преобразовании строки в число, когда в списке присутствуют только целые числа от 1 до 9-ти и сравниваются в запросе тоже с числом.

Вопрос: как правильно сделать отбор по реквизиту документа с типом число в T-SQL запросе (сравнить со списком чисел, передаваемом в запрос)?

Вот код, который выполняет T-SQL запрос:

```
RS = СоздатьОбъект("ODBCRecordSet");
RS.Отладка(0);

ТекстЗапроса = "
|SELECT 
|    СпрНоменклатура.ID as [Товар $Справочник.Номенклатура],
|    SUM($ДокС.Количество) as Количество 
|FROM
|    $ДокументСтроки.Документ1С as ДокС 
|INNER JOIN  
|       $Документ.Документ1С as Док ON Док.IDDoc = ДокС.IDDoc  
|INNER JOIN                                        
|    _1SJourn as Жур ON Жур.IDDoc = ДокС.IDDoc 
|                  AND  Жур.IDDocDef = $ВидДокумента.Документ1С
|                  AND  Жур.Date_Time_IDDoc BETWEEN :НачДата AND :КонДата~
|                  AND  Жур.Closed & 1 = 1
|LEFT JOIN
| $Справочник.Фирмы as СпрФирмы ON (СпрФирмы.ID = Жур.$ОбщийРеквизит.Фирма) 
|LEFT JOIN
| $Справочник.Номенклатура as СпрНоменклатура ON (СпрНоменклатура.ID = $ДокС.Товар)
|LEFT JOIN 
|   $Справочник.МестаХранения as СпрСклады ON (СпрСклады.ID = $Док.Склад)
|WHERE
|    $Док.Склад IN (SELECT Val FROM #ТабВыбСклады) 
|AND СпрФирмы.ID = :ВыбФирма 
|AND $Док.ДопПараметр IN (SELECT Val FROM #ТабВыбХодки)
|GROUP BY
|     СпрНоменклатура.ID  
|";

RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("НачДата" ,НачДата);
RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("КонДата" ,КонДата);
RS.УложитьСписокОбъектов(ВыбСклады, "#ТабВыбСклады", "МестаХранения"); 
RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("ВыбФирма" ,ВыбФирма);
RS.УложитьСписокОбъектов13(ВыбДопПараметр, "#ТабВыбДопПараметр");
//RS.УложитьСписокОбъектов(ВыбДопПараметр, "#ТабВыбДопПараметр");

вртаб = СоздатьОбъект("ТаблицаЗначений"); 
вртаб = RS.ВыполнитьИнструкцию(ТекстЗапроса); 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Параметры:    НачДата,КонДата - тип Дата, выбираются на форме,
//                  ВыбСклады - список из ссылок справочников "Места хранения", задается на форме обработки;
//                  ВыбФирма - поле формы обработки, в который заносится ссылка на справочник "Фирмы";
//                  ВыбДопПараметр - список из целых чисел (до 10-ти), задается на форме обработки; 
//
//Документ1С - это любой документ 1С 7.7, в котором в реквизитах шапки есть реквизит "Склад", значением которого является справочник "Места Хранения",
//          и реквизит "ДопПараметр", значение которого есть число длина 1, точность 0.
//          Есть общий реквизит документов "Фирма", значением которого является ссылка на справочник "Фирмы".
//          Кроме того в табличной части документа есть реквизит "Товар" с типом значения справочник "Номенклатура" и 
//          реквизит "Количество", значение которого есть число длина 13, точность 3. 
//          
//          Вобщем это практически любой документ любой конфигурации с табличной частью , кроме того что в шапку документа добавлен реквизит
//          "ДопПараметр".
```

Comment: Попробуй для начала сравнивать с единственным значением ВыбДопПараметр; Кроме этого попробуй устанавливать его через RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("ТабВыбДопПараметр" ,ВыбДопПараметр); Так возможно что-то выяснится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый вечер всем!

Нашел решение проблемы.
  Порывшись более тщательно на просторах интернета и в результате экспериментов, я выяснил, что T-SQL запрос корректно выбирает числа в конструкции "IN" с последующей
  записью цифр в скобках. Например запись "SELECT A IN (1.2.3)" корректно осуществляет отбор по этой группе цифр.
  Соответственно я ушел от попыток как-то передать через параметр список чисел в T-SQL запрос. В моем случае необходимо было преобразовать соответствующий
  список выбранных на форме чисел в строку и произвести конкатенацию строк непосредственно в тексте запроса.
  Результирующий работающий код представлен ниже.

```
СтрВыбДопПараметр = СтрЗаменить(ЗначениеВСтрокуВнутр(ВыбДопПараметр), """", "");   
СтрВыбДопПараметр = СтрЗаменить(СтрВыбДопПараметр, "{N,0,0,0,0,0," , "");
СтрВыбДопПараметр = СтрЗаменить(СтрВыбДопПараметр, ",}" , "");
СтрВыбДопПараметр = СтрЗаменить(СтрВыбДопПараметр, "{VL,{{" , ""); 
СтрВыбДопПараметр = СтрЗаменить(СтрВыбДопПараметр, "{" , ""); 
СтрВыбДопПараметр = СтрЗаменить(СтрВыбДопПараметр, "}" , "");

RS = СоздатьОбъект("ODBCRecordSet");
RS.Отладка(0);

ТекстЗапроса = "
|SELECT 
|    СпрНоменклатура.ID as [Товар $Справочник.Номенклатура],
|    SUM($ДокС.Количество) as Количество 
|FROM
|    $ДокументСтроки.Документ1С as ДокС 
|INNER JOIN  
|       $Документ.Документ1С as Док ON Док.IDDoc = ДокС.IDDoc  
|INNER JOIN                                        
|    _1SJourn as Жур ON Жур.IDDoc = ДокС.IDDoc 
|                  AND  Жур.IDDocDef = $ВидДокумента.Документ1С
|                  AND  Жур.Date_Time_IDDoc BETWEEN :НачДата AND :КонДата~
|                  AND  Жур.Closed & 1 = 1
|LEFT JOIN
| $Справочник.Фирмы as СпрФирмы ON (СпрФирмы.ID = Жур.$ОбщийРеквизит.Фирма) 
|LEFT JOIN
| $Справочник.Номенклатура as СпрНоменклатура ON (СпрНоменклатура.ID = $ДокС.Товар)
|LEFT JOIN 
|   $Справочник.МестаХранения as СпрСклады ON (СпрСклады.ID = $Док.Склад)
|WHERE
|    $Док.Склад IN (SELECT Val FROM #ТабВыбСклады) 
|AND СпрФирмы.ID = :ВыбФирма
|";
Если ПустоеЗначение(ВыбДопПараметр) = 0 Тогда 
    ТекстЗапроса=ТекстЗапроса+"   
    |AND $Док.ДопПараметр IN " +  "(" + СтрВыбДопПараметр + ")
    |"; 
КонецЕсли;

ТекстЗапроса = ТекстЗапроса +
"
|GROUP BY
|     СпрНоменклатура.ID  
|";

RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("НачДата" ,НачДата);
RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("КонДата" ,КонДата);
RS.УложитьСписокОбъектов(ВыбСклады, "#ТабВыбСклады", "МестаХранения"); 
RS.УстановитьТекстовыйПараметр("ВыбФирма" ,ВыбФирма);

вртаб = СоздатьОбъект("ТаблицаЗначений"); 
вртаб = RS.ВыполнитьИнструкцию(ТекстЗапроса);
```